# Exclude public pages from access control list

Tags: php, symfony, acl

I have application in Symfony2 with 2 roles: ROLE_ADMIN and ROLE_PARTNER. Also I have some public pages. All public pages starts with URL "/public/". I want to protect all application excluded these public items.

My current config:

```
access_control:
    - { path: /.*, role: ROLE_PARTNER|ROLE_ADMIN }
    - { path: /public/.*, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

But it works wrong (looping redirection).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Change the order:

```
access_control:
    - { path: ^/public/, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/, role: ROLE_PARTNER|ROLE_ADMIN }
```

The second option is to turn off security for the public section completely:

```
firewalls:
    public:
        pattern: ^/public/
        security: false
```

Comment: You helped me with help of @Carlos Granados

Comment: This solution is probably the clearest. One thing to keep in mind though; In my situation the secured area was `^/` and I had to exclude `^/api`. I had to list the `^/api` definition "before" the overall `^/` definition to make it work.

Answer (score 3):

Add:

```
- { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

See "Common Pitfalls" in http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#using-a-traditional-login-form

Comment: You helped me with help of @elnur